# exact ID search with Lucene.net 3.0.3

Tags: vb.net, lucene.net

I am trying to find a document by the indexed value (PAR-17-252).  I indexed the field using

```
    Dim d As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = FSDirectory.Open(New DirectoryInfo(p))
        Dim a As Analyzer = New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30)
        Dim indexWriter As IndexWriter = New IndexWriter(d, a, True, indexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)            

        doc.Add(New Field("GrantID", dr("GrantID").ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))
```

And I search with

```
        term = term.Replace("-", " ")
        term = term.Replace("/", " ")

            Dim phases As String() = Nothing
            phases = Split(term, ",")
            For Each phase As String In phases
                q.Add(parser.Parse(phase), Occur.SHOULD)
            Next
```

Now I know that the "-" causes a problem but I don't know how to handle it.  If I don't take it out of the search term I get back nothing if I leave it in I get back nothing.  The PAR-17-252 is a record name index. If I take it out and try to search for the phrase "PAR 17 252" I still get nothing.

Any help is appreciated.  I've read just about everything here about Lucene.net and still having some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You want to search that field with [KeywordAnalyzer](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/df/d85/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_keyword_analyzer.html).  Here's some C# that demonstrates KeywordAnalyzer for your use case, sorry it's not vb.net - but you should get the gist.

```
var field_GrantID = "GrantID";
var field_value = "PAR-17-252";
var luceneVer = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30;

using (var writer = new IndexWriter(new RAMDirectory(), new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVer), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
{
    var doc = new Document();
    // NOT_ANALYZED means index the field as presented.
    doc.Add(new Field(field_GrantID, field_value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    writer.AddDocument(doc);
    writer.Commit();

    using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader()))
    {            
        var parser = new QueryParser(luceneVer, field_GrantID, new KeywordAnalyzer());
        var queryText = String.Format("{0}:{1}", field_GrantID, field_value);
        var query = parser.Parse(queryText);
        var topDocs = searcher.Search(query, null, 100);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Hits for query {0} : {1}", query, topDocs.TotalHits);
    }
}
```

You'll likely want to search more than one field, check out [MultiFieldQueryParser](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d6/d0b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_query_parsers_1_1_multi_field_query_parser.html#ab23ac6174e400100db7b842625aa286d)

Comment: This is great- I'll give it a try.  I think I finally need to start writting in C# anyway.  Thanks